# How to change the Android in-app product local prices through Android publisher?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

The back end server of our system is supposed to update the prices of user-created in-app products for our Android app in Google Play store. The back end is written in C# and we use the "patch" service of Android Publisher to do that with the option "autoConvertMissingPrices" switched to "true".

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/patch

However, all it does is change the default price while the local prices stay unchanged. I guess we need something like the "overwrite existing prices" checkbox which is in the in-app products section of Google Play Developer Console but in the programmer's interface.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you solve it? I've run into the same issue. Getting invalid price.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've solved it by changing the PATCH for PUT