# Default versus local prices in Google play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I am puzzled by the function of the default price and auto price conversion for in-app products in Google play developer console. And I am sorry that the question itself is also written in a little confused way :).

I read a couple of sources online but it still seems unclear:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947?hl=en

Is it obligatory to fill the local price for each of the countries where I want to distribute the app? Or can I somehow leave the local price empty and have it converted from the default price at the time of purchase? It seems the former is true, because the gui wouldn't let me save a product with some of the local prices empty. If so, why there needs to be a special check box to "overwrite existing prices" when editing a product? Without this check box, nothing would happen so everyone needs to check it always. And what is the default price used for, if all the countries with specific currencies must have their own local price?

(
This question is related to [How to change the Android in-app product local prices through Android publisher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533440/how-to-change-the-android-in-app-product-local-prices-through-android-publisher) . If the local prices cannot be left empty, than the "autoConvertMissingPrices" switch of Android Publisher patch service doesn't make much sense.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/patch
)